# How to stop Emacs from highlighting Linux Tab characters?

Tags: highlighting, tabs, whitespace-mode

So I opened a c++ script made in Xubuntu and every tab character was highlighted with grey.
That doesn't happen when I open scripts made on Windows. How do I stop Emacs from highlighting them, it's very distracting?
Here is a picture of what it looks like:
[image: example]

Comment: A guess is that you're using `whitespace-mode`, which is highlighting the Tab chars. Check the mode you're using for the buffers in GNU/Linux vs Microsoft Windows. Sounds like one of them turns on `whitespace-mode` and the other doesn't. Just a guess.

Comment: Put the cursor on one of those Tab chars and hit `C-u C-x =`. The `*Help*` will tell you what faces are used to highlight them. Work from that info to find out what code (maybe `whitespace-mode`) is doing the highlighting.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check the settings and preferences as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `whitespace-mode` turned on. Turn it off.

Comment: (Or configure its [`whitespace-style`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html) to your liking.)